# Can't edit text in UITextField

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitextfield

In  my app, when I try to edit (type some text) `UITextField`,the cursor just blinks but no characters are typed in except BACKSPACE (possible only when I have some initial text in it), RETURN and switching character types.

this is how I declared `UITextField`

```
 txtmail =[[UITextField alloc]init];
            [txtmail setFrame:CGRectMake(288, 51,264, 31)];
            [txtmail setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
            [txtmail setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",appDelegate.Email]];
            [txtmail setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"TimesNewRoman" size:14]];
            txtmail.textColor =[UIColor grayColor];
            txtmail.delegate=self;
            [testScroll addSubview:txtmail];
```

in my .h file I have given like this

```
 @interface pot: UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
{
    UITextField *txtmail;
}
```

Comment: does the keyboard appear when you click on the text field?

Comment: `[testScroll addSubview:txtemail];` have spell mistake

Comment: are you adding textmail or txtemail as subview which is correct?

Comment: are you sure your txtmail is added in your scrollview

Comment: The textField that you are added mistakenly by another One (txtemail)

Comment: Can you paste your .h file code

Comment: Now you are edit this question , still you have same problem.

Comment: @user2197875 you are setting txtmail and adding to subview txtemail, which now you have corrected.

Comment: @user2197875: please paste your .h file code

Comment: @user2197875: please set the Delegate properly <UITextFieldDelegate>

Comment: @user2197875 Declared in .h as txtemail and in .m you are using as txtmail

Comment: is it for iphone or ipad ??

Comment: for both iphone and ipad

Comment: once set the frame as CGRectMake(50, 51,150, 31) and setText:@"Sample" and check and let me know what is coming

Comment: @user2197875 Please post your UITextFieldDelegate Methods , may be its pro in that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just replace this methods with your that class's methods,

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    return YES;
}    
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

    return YES;
}
```